# AWS Lambda Serverless endpoint exits without executing function

Tags: post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, x-www-form-urlencoded

We have a POST endpoint in our serverless api which listens to a Magento 2 integration activation callback and processes the payload. The Content-Type of this callback request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. However, when we try to get the callback, the lambda function finishes execution immediately, skipping the entire function body. What we see in the Cloudwatch logs is only this. Not even `console.log`s are printed. (the endpoint only prints a string to the console. No async operations are in place. Yet this problem persists)

```
2020-12-12T12:24:47.012+05:30 START RequestId: 4afba03d-54ef-4b5e-bd44-157b0b7a9f9b Version: $LATEST
2020-12-12T12:24:47.050+05:30 END RequestId: 4afba03d-54ef-4b5e-bd44-157b0b7a9f9b
2020-12-12T12:24:47.050+05:30 REPORT RequestId: 4afba03d-54ef-4b5e-bd44-157b0b7a9f9b    Duration: 37.83 ms  Billed Duration: 38 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 109 MB Init Duration: 893.79 ms
```

When we try to hit the same endpoint from POSTMAN with Content-Type: application/json, the endpoint works as expected.

Therefore we thought that the problem might be the `Content-Type` header and read somewhere that adding request mapping templated would solve this problem. Therefore, we even added a mapping template for content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the integration request of the lambda method with following content, time to time. But our problem was not solved unfortunately.

```
"{ "body": "$util.base64Decode($input.body)" }"
```

```
{
"formparams" : $input.json('$')
}
```

```
{
    "body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

My question is: **How we can set the endpoint to print the POST request payload, preventing it from immediate exiting?**
We have been searching for a solution to this problem since a week. It would be a great help, if someone can input their helpful, valuable suggestions to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Content-Type` of the Magento 2 Integration activation callback is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the lambda event for that POST request was something like this.

```
console.log(event) -> {body: "a=var&b=other_var&c=another_var"}
```

The endpoint didn't even print anything because I had put `console.log(JSON.parse(event. body))`. This results in a JSON parse error and the endpoint immediately finishes execution.

When I started parsing the query parameter event body instead of `JSON.parse()`, the problem was solved.